# How to link to local pdf file with full path

Tags: hyperref, texshop, paths, hyperlink

I want to add a link to `/Users/p/foo.pdf`, but when I hover over the link in TeXShop it seems to be a link to `<pwd>/Users/p/foo.pdf`.

I guess that I could include the correct number of `../` at the start of the path to get this to work, but is there some easier way?

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\begin{document} 
    \href{run:/Users/p/foo.pdf}{Link to foo.pdf}
\end{document}
```

Comment: For me this is kind of viewer-dependent. While the TeXworks internal viewer works for `file://<path>`, Evince does not.